# What was the "real" first equation?

Tags: math-history, mathematicians

The first equation ever written, using a modern equals sign, has TWO versions:

Version 1:

[Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Recorde)
and
[Another link](https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-first-equation-used-for)
gives

$$ 14x+15=71 $$

But from a UK maths textbook, it gives

$$ 14\sqrt{x}+15=71 $$

So which one is the correct interpretation of the picture:
[image]

Comment: Most websites seem to suggest that it is 14x + 15 = 71, but I think it is open to interpretation. I don't think this is a very good question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to History of Science and Mathematics SE.

Comment: Isn't it the case of transferring this question to History of Science and Mathematics SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an online translation of the original text,

[image]

Clearly the answer is 4 (as shown in the last phrase), so the equation must be
14x + 15 = 71 and *not* $14 \sqrt{x} + 15 = 71$.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate, as in both cases **the symbol** equals $\;4\;$: either $\;x=4\;$ or $\;\sqrt x=4\;$ . Observe that in the last line he's using the same symbol as in the first one...

Comment: Does that symbol look like a square root?